# Find n given an inequality involving the sum of log

Tags: real-analysis

For $n\in \mathbb{N},$ there is a function given by, $f(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\log(1-\frac{i}{N}),$ with $N = 365, n\leq N,$ whereby $\log$ is supposed to mean the natural logarithm. I need to find the largest $n$ such that $f(n)\leq -\log(2).$ I thought first to use the Taylor expansion of $f$ and based on the given inequality to find $n$. But since the domain is discrete, it does not seem to be plausible. Do you have any suggestion or solution proposal ? Thanks.

Comment: I doubt there's a closed formula—this looks like a compute-everything-explicitly problem (presumably related to the birthday paradox). Note that it's easy to compute many values of $f(n)$ in a row since each one is just one term added to the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an *approximation*, use the continuous case and write
$$f(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\log\left(1-\frac{i}{N}\right)\sim g(n)$$ with $$g(n)= \int_{1}^{n}\log\left(1-\frac{i}{N}\right)\,di$$

$$g(n)=1-n-(N-n) \log \left(1-\frac{n}{N}\right)+(N-1) \log \left(\frac{N-1}{N}\right)$$

Let $n=k N$ and expand as a series for large values of $N$

$$g(n)=-N ((1-k) \log (1-k)+k)+\frac{1}{2 N}+O\left(\frac{1}{N^2}\right)$$

Just keep the first term of the expansion and expand again around $k=0$ to obtain
$$-\frac N 2 \left(k^2+\frac{k^3}{3}+O\left(k^4\right)   \right)$$ If you do not want to solve more than a quadratic equation, the equality will happen at
$$k\sim \sqrt{\frac{2 \log (2)}{N}} \quad \implies \quad n\sim  \sqrt{2 N\log (2)} $$  For $N=365$, this would give $n\sim 22.5$ that you can round the way you want.

Solving exactly the first definition of $g(n)$, the solution is $22.3$ while using $f(n)$ the solution is $n=22$.

Nothing very sophisticated, as you can see it.